# "Disable horizontal scroll on Apple MBP multi touch trackpad"

Tags: scroll, trackpad

How can I disable horizontal scrolling (while keeping vertical scrolling enabled) on an Apple mult-touch trackpad, specifically while creating a Word document? This has been asked often in Mac forums, but nobody has posted an answer. And neither has Apple. Running OS 10.6.8 on a mid-2010 MacBook Pro.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple products and belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.  According to the following Apple support page (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3448):
"Mac notebooks without Multi-Touch trackpads have the option to disable horizontal scrolling or to disable scrolling completely whereas Multi-Touch trackpads can only adjust scrolling speed."

One can only hope that Apple will see the wisdom of reinstating this intuitive & highly useful option in the future.

Comment: I don't agree. To me this looks like a useful answer.